# Error when using guards in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I created the following code in Haskell:

```
eqs a b c 
| ((b^2) - (4*a*c)) < 0 = "MESSAGE"
| otherwise =  "x1= " ++ show (sqrt((-b + ((b^2) - (4*a*c))))2*a) ++ "x2= " show (sqrt((-b - ((b^2) - (4*a*c))))2*a)
```

Why do I get the following error message?

> ERROR file:.\file.hs:2 - Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `;', possibly due to bad layout)

Comment: @Sandeep Biradar: code formatting is for code only. Haskell is not code, it's a proper name.

Comment: @Mat i did it for highlighting it.

Comment: There are a whole lot of problems with your code, but none causes the error you quoted. Please post the exact contents of the file you tried to compile.

Comment: Guards should be indented more: try adding one or two spaces before each `|`. This will not fix all errors, but let's start with that.

Comment: @SandeepBiradar: do not use code formatting for non-code. If normal English needs highlighting, use bold or italics (and use very little of it). No highlighting is necessary here anyway, just proper capitalization.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, the style of error message makes me wonder if the OP is using Hugs for some reason.

Comment: I guess your `sqrt` arguments are wrong, and turn out to be negative. Note that they are not the same as the value used in the guard above...

Comment: @chi thanks! I took your advice and I indented the guards. The code hasn't worked out all right as yet, but at least it fixed the bad layout error. And yes, I am using WinHugs.

The fixed code is below:

`eqs a b c 
  | ((b^2) - (4*a*c)) < 0 = "Nao existem raizes reais"
  | otherwise =  "x1= " ++ show ((-b + sqrt((b^2) - (4*a*c))) / (2*a)) ++ " x2= " ++ show (((-b - sqrt((b^2) - (4*a*c)))) / (2*a))`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The unique problem I see in your code is a type error, not the parser error you've posted. The type error is on the following expression:

```
 (-b + ((b^2) - (4*a*c))))2*a
```

I believe that you probably want to use division, so the correct expression should be

```
 (-b + ((b^2) - (4*a*c)))) / (2*a)
```

Hope that this can help you. In order to better help you, please consider to post the whole content of your Haskell program file.